# Getting scipy to work in cygwin

Tags: scipy, cygwin

I know that others have struggled with this problem, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have installed anything I can see related to gcc, BLAS, or LAPACK in the cygwin packages window, but I still get a long list of errors when I do `pip install scipy`. I see things like

```
 Running from scipy source directory.
 Splitting linalg.interpolative Fortran source files
 blas_opt_info:
 blas_mkl_info:
   libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
   NOT AVAILABLE

 openblas_info:
   libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
   NOT AVAILABLE
```

The last error I see is:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-8lzrOH/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nzff
hk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8lzrOH/scipy
```

Can someone help me out with this? Numpy is working without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Cygwin Setup, install `liblapack-devel` (openblas will come as dependency). Then you can install *scipy* with `pip install scipy`.

Comment: Is the -devel version required?
I'm also having this problem, but it I get the following:
----
I get ..3.9//distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
Then can't find any version of fortran,a dn that MATLIB should be setup.
-----
thanks
 
Thanks for any help

Comment: @eorojas you can search for `openblas` or `libopenblas` in cygwin. However, if your problem presents a completely different error message, I'd recommend you create a new question in Stack Overflow to explore it.